# How do I find the four solutions of a quartic equation expressed as a quadratic squared?

Tags: complex-numbers

How would I solve $(2+x-x^{2})^{2}=16$ to find the roots. I managed to get the correct solution by expanding it to a quartic and then using my calculator's polynomial equation solver, but I'm guessing there's another way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, note that $16 = 4^2$, so it follows that $2 + x - x^2 = 4$ or $2 + x - x^2 = -4$.